# How can I get and install Intel GMA HD Driver on Acer Aspire One D255

Tags: installation, drivers, 12.10, intel-graphics

How can I get and install Intel GMA HD Driver on Acer Aspire One D255? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal i386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'software sources' and go to 'additional drivers' tab.

You may find your Driver there :)

If you don't find it there then try looking here :

[Search here for Intel Drivers : http://downloadcenter.intel.com/](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/)